# Given two insights into the distribution of a normally distribution of data, can I determine the mean?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mean

If I was told, 81% of students have a gpa higher than a 3.0 and 44% of students have a gpa over a 3.5. Assuming the data is normally distributed, how would I go about determining the mean of the distribution.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: @MichaelChernick this isn't a textbook problem. My school doesn't release the mean gpa, and I got some of this data from a printout and want to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: It is a test type question which means that it requires the self study tag, It doesn't have to be taken from a text book or an exam.

Answer (score 1):

You have two values to consider, let $X$ be the GPA:
$$P(X<3)=0.19, P(X<3.5)=0.56$$
Standardizing inner expressions:
$$P(Z<(3-\mu)/\sigma)=\phi((3-\mu)/\sigma)=0.19$$ $$P(Z<(3.5-\mu)/\sigma)=\phi((3.5-\mu)/\sigma)=0.56$$

Using z-table, we can find the associated $z$ values as $(3-\mu)/\sigma \approx -0.875$ and $(3.5-\mu)/\sigma \approx 0.15$. When you solve these, you’ll not only obtain the mean but also the standard deviation.